# using a linear solver to get a "centre of gravity" of a set of points

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, geometry, algorithm, optimization

As a programmer, if I have a **linear solver** available. How can I formulate the following problem as a set of **constrains / decisions / goals** for the linear solver?

I have a matrix of say **10*10**, so **100** points (potential depots).

I randomly select **10** of those points as **"Customers"**.

Now I would like to "solve" the point(s) totalling the **shortest distance** from the 10 "Customers" and I would like the coordinates of that point.

One "depot" point is so easy it doesn't need a solver, however solving the two "depot" points that combine to give the shortest distances to all the "customers" is tough, so needs a solver.

I can use the **K-means** to do this, however I would like to know if and how I can use a linear solver to do the same thing.

Comment: I think you are looking for the **Circumcenter**, of the convex hull formed of your points. The convex hull probably would be an irregular polygon, so the problem tranforms as the Smallest-circle problem. The center of that circle would be your ideal position, offering the shortest distance what would serve your points. Certainly is not the minimum average  distance.

Comment: @nickves I think I am after the minimum average distance using a linear solver.

Answer (score 2):

The objective is to find a point which minimizes the distance; which mathematically it means that your first derivation of the distance equations needs to be equal with zero.  The order of the equations follow:

[image]

In the above equation x and y is the coordinates you are looking for, and with the subscript are the coordinates of your known location. My geometrical interpertation of the above equation would be, that the point with the minimum distance from a set of points, would that point itself.

In matrix format we can re write it as :

[image]

```
A        X   =      L
```

So if you had 3 points with coordinates p1 = (3,3) p2 = (10,10) and p3 = (1,1)
the matrices would get this following form:

[image]

The solution of the above is not possible using the familiar 
       `X = A^-1 L`

but you can use the **Least Squares Adjustment**, which tries to minimize the residuals of all the observations. The residuals in this case, is the distance. The solution can be calculated using a  linear solver by :

[image]

A pythonic interpertation using the np.linalg. module of numpy and the above points:

```
  import numpy as np
  A = np.array(((1,1),(1,1),(1,1)))
  L = np.array((6,20,2))
  res = np.linalg.lstsq(A,L)
  point = res[0] # (array([ 4.66666667,  4.66666667]))
```

where a is the coeficient matrix, and L is the observation matrix

NB1 : As you can see, **the result is the same if you take the average coordinates of your points**

so another way to reach the same result would be **res = (average(x), average(y))** without the need to use linear algebra.

NB2: Your result would be the point which is closer to the above.

Comment: Thanks nickves, I see your point about the result being the same as the average. Would this apply if I have to pick multiple best "depot" points? as that was my real goal, for one point it is much simpler.

Comment: I guess so. The aim is to serve the customers. If you choose 10 initial points (from your customers), you can derive the ideal solution to serve them. Of course the coordinates of the ideal would fall in the 'air' so the next best 'depot' to serve them would be the closest depot to the ideal. If I understood correctly

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was what would happen if I wanted more than one ideal. Suddenly the solution suggested does not seem to apply. At least the simple average does not.

Comment: The above applies if all the points have equal weight. I start to suspect that you want to put a distance weight The point  would be biased to be closer to where your 'customers' are more clustered. Other than that as far as I know, geometrically there is only one center of gravity.